# Reduce app CPU Usage in Android

Tags: android, multithreading, webview

My app shows a splash screen for 4 seconds and then opens another activity with a web view.
I am using a thread to splash the screen and finish() the first activity as soon as web view activity is started. I have also used animations like fade in and fade out.
It's CPU usage is fluctuating between 8% to 23%.What could be the reason. I want to reduce the CPU usage.
  My first activity that shows splash screen and starts web view activity-

```
           public class MainActivity extends Activity {
Thread splashThread;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    overridePendingTransition(R.animation.fadein,R.animation.fadeout); 

    getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     //-----------------------------------------

        splashThread=new Thread(){
        public void run()
        {
            try
            {   
                sleep(1000);                    
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            finally
            {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),OpenWeb.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
    };
    splashThread.start();
     //-----------------------------------------

    super.onStart();
    overridePendingTransition(R.animation.fadein, R.animation.fadeout);
}
@Override
protected void onStop() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    finish();
    super.onRestart();
} 
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to reduce CPU usage? 20% isn't that bad. Whatever CPU load measurement you get is probably due to the animations, but profile to make sure.

Answer (score -1):

Could be that you used alot of imports something like. I heard that uses alot of cpu?

```
import android.graphics.*
```

Are you using a AVD?

Comment: Imports don't use any CPU in the executed app whatsover. They just might make the *build* a tiny bit slower.

Comment: I am using real android device.

Comment: I am using CPU monitor app for testing CPU usage of app.